# Как скрывать приложение при выполнение команд в cmd? - C#

Tags: c#, cmd

Проект - Windows Forms (приложение)

Подскажите как правильно скрыть приложение если в командной строке cmd написать команду:

```
C:\app.exe /h
```

Необходимо для того, чтобы управлять приложением через локальную сеть или через планировщик Windows используя ярлык приложения.

При этом в приложении такой код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    private void Form1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] passedInArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        foreach (string s in passedInArgs)
        {
            if (s.ToUpperInvariant() == "/H")
            {
                this.Hide();
                RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\TEST002");
                key.SetValue("000", "111");
                key.Close();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey("SOFTWARE\\TEST002", false);
            }
        }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы пишете прямо в HKLM? o_O

Comment: И что означает «скрыть приложение»? Скрыть _уже бегущее_ приложение, или запустить новый экземпляр приложения без отображения окна?

Comment: Скрыть - без отображения окна (т.е. формы приложения). Чтобы при выполнении задачи в планировщике, приложение не открывалось пользователю при вводе команды /h

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden

Comment: NMD - не помогло, неужели нет кода который игнорирует появление окна формы, если к приложению обращаются через cmd с командой /h